# Integral's Closed-form expression in terms of hypergeometric function

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I want to solve the following integral:

> $$I = 2\left[\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{y^m}{(1 - ay)^{m + 1}\sqrt{1 - y^2}}\mathrm{d}y+\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{y^m}{(1 + ay)^{m + 1}\sqrt{1 - y^2}}\mathrm{d}y\right]$$

where $0 \leq a \leq 1$ and $m$ is an arbitrary positive constant.

I have tried to expand each term of the above integral in series form and solve it. I have got answer in an infinite series form, which is not a closed-form expression.

Infinite series expression (Derivation is given below):
$$
\boxed{
I = 4\sum_{t = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{\underset{u \neq \text{Odd}}{u=0}}^{t}\frac{a^u(m+1)_{u}}{u!}\frac{(1/2)_{t-u}}{(t-u)!}\frac{1}{(m+1)+2t-u}.}
$$

However, Maple gives a beautiful closed-form expression in terms of hypergeometric function, which is as follows:

$$I = \frac{2^{m+1}\left[\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma\left(\frac{m + 1}{2}\right)^2 {_2F_1\left(\left[\frac{m + 1}{2},\frac{m+ 1}{2}\right], \left[\frac{1}{2}\right], a^2\right)}\right]}{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma(m + 1)}$$

where ${_2F_1\left(\left[a, b\right], \left[w\right], z \right)}$ is a hypergeometric function.

How can I obtain the above expression given by Maple?

**Derivation of infinite series expression**: Following is the derivation for the infinite series expression that I could figure out.

Let the first integral of $I$  be

$$I_1 = \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{y^m}{(1 - ay)^{m + 1}\sqrt{1 - y^2}}\mathrm{d}y = \int_{0}^{1} y^m(1 - ay)^{-(m + 1)}(1 - y^2)^{-1/2}\mathrm{d}y.$$ 
Then, we make use of the following relation
$$ (1 - y)^{-m} = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{(m)_{t}}{t!}y^{t}$$
where $(m)_{t}$ denotes the Pochhammer symbol and is defined as $(m)_{t} = (t)\times(m+1)\times\dotsc\times(m+t-1) = \frac{\Gamma(m+t)}{\Gamma(m)}$.
Then, we have
$$ (1 - ay)^{-(m+1)} = \sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{(m+1)_{t}}{t!}(ay)^{t}.$$
On the similar lines, one can write 
$$(1 - y^2)^{-1/2} = \sum_{u=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1/2)_{u}}{u!}y^{2u}.$$
Thus, $I_1$ can be written as
$$I_1 =  \int_{0}^{1} y^m\left(\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^t(m+1)_{t}}{t!}y^{t}\right)\left(\sum_{u=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1/2)_{u}}{u!}y^{2u}\right)\mathrm{d}y.$$
Simplifying further,
$$I_1 = \int_{0}^{1} \left(\sum_{t=0}^{\infty}\frac{a^t(m+1)_{t}}{t!}y^{t+m}\right)\left(\sum_{u=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1/2)_{u}}{u!}y^{2u}\right)\mathrm{d}y.$$
We make use of the following relation
$$
\left(\sum_{p=0}^{\infty}z_p\right)\left(\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}g_q\right) = \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{u=0}^{t}z_u g_{u-t}.
$$
Then, we can write
$$
I_1 = \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{u = 0}^{t}\frac{a^uy^{u+m}(m+1)_{u}}{u!}\frac{y^{2(t-u)}(1/2)_{t-u}}{(t-u)!}\mathrm{d}y.$$
Then,
$$
I_1 = \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{u = 0}^{t}\frac{a^u(m+1)_{u}}{u!}\frac{(1/2)_{t-u}}{(t-u)!}y^{(m+2t-u)}\mathrm{d}y.
$$
After integration, we can write
$$
I_1 = \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{u = 0}^{t}\frac{a^u(m+1)_{u}}{u!}\frac{(1/2)_{t-u}}{(t-u)!}\frac{1}{(m+1)+2t-u}.
$$
Similarly, 
$$
I_2 = \int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{y^m}{(1 + ay)^{m + 1}\sqrt{1 - y^2}}\mathrm{d}y = \sum_{t = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{u = 0}^{t}\frac{(-1)^u a^u(m+1)_{u}}{u!}\frac{(1/2)_{t-u}}{(t-u)!}\frac{1}{(m+1)+2t-u}.
$$
Thus, we can write $I$ as
$$
\boxed{
I = 4\sum_{t = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{\underset{u \neq \text{Odd}}{u=0}}^{t}\frac{a^u(m+1)_{u}}{u!}\frac{(1/2)_{t-u}}{(t-u)!}\frac{1}{(m+1)+2t-u}.}
$$

Comment: Have you tried writing $\frac{1}{(1-cx)^{p+1}}+\frac{1}{(1+cx)^{p+1}}$ as a Taylor series and integrating termwise through the Euler's Beta function?

Comment: Note that a hypergeometric function is in some sense just a particularly general form of an infinite series expansion. So it'd help if you included the infinite series you acquired, since it's possible you can translate it directly into Maple's expression.

Comment: @Semiclassical: I have edited the post and put the detailed derivation of the expression with infinite series expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Expand only the factors $(1\pm ay)^{-m-1}$ in powers of $a$ using
$$(1\mp ay)^{-m-1}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(m+1)_k}{k!}\left(\pm ay\right)^k,$$
where $(z)_k:=\displaystyle \frac{\Gamma(z+k)}{\Gamma(z)}$ denotes the [Pochhammer's symbol](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html). 
The odd powers clearly cancel out and even ones are equal for the two summands, hence we can write
$$I=4\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(m+1)_{2k}}{(2k)!} a^{2k}\int_0^{1}\frac{y^{2k+m}dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}.$$
The change of variables $y^2=x$ reduces the remaining integral to [Euler beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function):
$$\int_0^{1}\frac{y^{2k+m}dy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\frac12 \int_0^{1}\frac{x^{k+\frac{m-1}{2}}dx}{\sqrt{1-x}}=\frac12B\left(k+\frac{m+1}{2},\frac12\right)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{
\Gamma\left(k+1+\frac{m}{2}\right)},$$
so that the initial integral becomes
$$I=2\sqrt\pi \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(m+1)_{2k}}{(2k)!}\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{
\Gamma\left(k+1+\frac{m}{2}\right)} a^{2k}.\tag{1}$$
Let us now rewrite the expression for the coefficient of this series using the gamma function [duplication formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDuplicationFormula.html) $\Gamma(2z)=\displaystyle\frac{2^{2z-1}}{\sqrt\pi}\Gamma\left(z\right)\Gamma\left(z+\frac12\right)$. We get
\begin{align*}
\frac{(m+1)_{2k}}{(2k)!}\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{
\Gamma\left(k+1+\frac{m}{2}\right)}&=\frac{\color{red}{\Gamma\left(2k+m+1\right)}\Gamma\left(k+\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{\color{red}{\Gamma\left(2k+1\right)}\Gamma\left(m+1\right)
\Gamma\left(k+1+\frac{m}{2}\right)}=\\
&=\color{red}{2^m\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{m+1}2\right)\Gamma\left(k+1+\frac{m}2\right)}{\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right)\Gamma\left(k+1\right)}}\frac{\Gamma\left(k+\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(m+1\right)
\Gamma\left(k+1+\frac{m}{2}\right)}=\\
&=\frac{2^m}{\Gamma(m+1)}\frac{\Gamma^2\left(k+\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{k!\,\Gamma\left(k+\frac12\right)}=\\
&=\frac{2^m\Gamma^2\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt\pi \,\Gamma(m+1)}\cdot
\frac{\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)_k\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)_k}{k!\,\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k}.
\end{align*}
This immediately reduces the series (1) to the defining [series representation of the hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series):
$$ 
\boxed{\quad\displaystyle I=2^{m+1}\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{\,\Gamma(m+1)}\,_2F_1\left[\frac{m+1}{2},\frac{m+1}{2};\frac12;a^2\right]\quad}$$